# Biztalk Server 2020: Invalid Character found

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

When sending EDI INVOIC I receive the following error:

> Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BatchSuspendOrchestration.BatchElementSuspendService(52b477a6-f224-d7ee-a40d-92c8ad5f5544)'.
> The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated.
> If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
> InstanceId: 2194c57a-bdb1-4bb7-9c7b-9e6f884af3a2
> Shape name: Throw that an error has occured
> ShapeId: 209c5624-f52a-404d-b44d-d8fb41b0fed4
> Exception thrown from: segment 2, progress 33
> Inner exception: The batch element is being suspended as it either failed schema validation or context properties are not matching batch definition. The error is : Stopping after the first error !!
> Error: 1 (Field level error)
> SegmentID: FTX
> Position in TS: 5
> Data Element ID: C10801
> Position in Segment: 5
> Position in Field: 1
> Data Value: Bezüglich der späteren Entgeltminderung verweisen wir auf die
> 21:

This happens only by two out three identities of the partner and only it the text contains umlauts. Only this partner has this problem, every other partner is not affected.

I've change everything, change encoding, ports, etc.

Comment: Which EDIFACT Character Set is set on the partner agreement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/edi-character-sets

Comment: The Character Set is UNOC.

Comment: And does the payload also say it is UNOC?

Comment: Not sure that i understand your question.  Where should i check that?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the business profiles and agreements, and recreating them with the same settings. That solved my problem but it would be good to know why it didn't work from the beginning.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve it.  Must have been something wrong in the agreement then.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer that helped you by using the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

[EDI Character Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/edi-character-sets) (Microsoft.com)

> An EDIFACT-encoded interchange is self-describing in terms of its character set. The UNB1 data element is used. EDIFACT requires that tag names and separators/delimiters are ASCII types; as a result, locating UNB1 to apply the relevant code page for the remaining interchange is possible.

So check the UNB1, and I think you will find that it in probably UNOA or UNOB that don't support those characters.  If it is, then your partner needs to update it at their end to have the correct character encoding set in the payload.

See also [EDIFACT Encoding – EDI Character Set Support](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2009/08/15/edifact-encoding-edi-character-set-support/) (Sandro Pereira's blog)

Comment: The one-way agreements are already set to UNOC. Also in the fallback settings the UNB1.1 is set to UNOC. I've sent the message through another agreement of the partner with no problem. the only diference between the two agreements are only the sender.